# Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2110, 1)

Tags: dnn9

I want to predict stock price and I've defined my model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu',
                       input_shape=(window, train.shape[1],)),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)])
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9,
                                              beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False))
history = model.fit(train_dataset, train_labels, epochs=150)
```

I get this error:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2110, 1)
```

note: my input is (2110, 22, 16) but my output is (2110,1). 2110 is number of examples.

I need help to fix this.